# Выбрать строку, в которую необходимо перенести информацию непосредственно во время перетаскивания

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, drag-n-drop

Здравствуйте    ( ´ ▽ ` )ﾉ

### **Цель:**

При перетаскивании объекта из одного DataGridView в другой, во время перетаскивания указать строку, в которую мы хотим переместить объект

---

### **Что я пробовал**

Методы ниже выполняются в обработчике событий принимающего DataGridView

1. Событие `MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)`

   ```
   private void dtDinnerType_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       if ((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
       {
           DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = dtDinnerType.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
           if (hit.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)
           {
               dtDinnerType.Rows[hit.RowIndex].Selected = true;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Данный метод выполнял свою работу как надо, до тех пор пока я не зажимал левую 
   кнопку мыши (Перетаскивал), после он просто не выполняет событие `MouseMove`, 
   когда я вожу по объекту с зажатой кнопкой мыши, стоит мне отжать мышь и событие 
   выполняет свою работу, но не проходит проверку в методе, что правильно
2. Событие `CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)`

   ```
   private void dtDinnerType_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {
       if ((MouseButtons & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
       {
           DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = dtDinnerType.HitTest(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
           if (hit.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)
           {
               dtDinnerType.Rows[hit.RowIndex].Selected = true;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Проблемам аналогична с методом выше
3. Событие `DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)`

   ```
   private void dtDinnerType_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {
       DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = dtDinnerType.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
       if (hit.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)
       {
           //Работа со строкой на которую мы навели 
       } 
   }
   ```

   Проблема в этом методе мне непонятна, `dtDinnerType.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)`, в данном случае этот метод возвращает:
    `hit: {{ Type:None, Column:-1, Row:-1 }}` и `hit.Type == None`
   Ведь при отпускании мы находимся над строкой в DGV и тест должен быть положительный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо перевести координаты DragEventArgs в координаты, относительные DataGridView:

```
Point clientPoint = dtDinnerType.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = dtDinnerType.HitTest(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y);
```